# Member function captured by lambda asynchronously dispatch issue

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, lambda, concurrency

As we know, if we have a lambda that captures class members and the lambda is called asynchronously after the class object is released, then it should crash. But if the lambda captures "this", and call this->memFunc() after the class object is released, seems it works OK. I cannot understand why it doesn't crash. See code v1.

```cpp
class A:
{
public:
    int func()
    {
        std::ofstream myfile("example.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            myfile << "Write from child thread.\n";
            myfile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to open file";
        }
    }

    void detach()
    {
        std::thread t([this]() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000));
            func();
        });
        t.detach();
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        A a;
        a.detach();
    }

    std::cout << "main end" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    return 0;
}
```

v2:

```
#define RETURN_FROM_LAMBDA_IF_DEAD(x) \
    auto sharedThis = x.lock(); \
    if(!sharedThis) \
        return;

class A: public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    int func()
    {
        std::ofstream myfile("example.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            myfile << "Write from child thread.\n";
            myfile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to open file";
        }
    }

    void detach()
    {
        std::thread t([weakThis = weak_from_this(), this]() {
            RETURN_FROM_LAMBDA_IF_DEAD(weakThis);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000));
            func();
        });
        t.detach();
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        A a;
        a.detach();
    }

    std::cout << "main end" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    return 0;
}
```

class A has a member function detach() that will create a child thread. The child thread accepts a lambda in which A's member function func() will be called.

When main thread prints "main end", the object a should be released, so when its child thread calls a's func(), it should crash. But a's func() runs ok and "example.txt" created successfully.

Why a's func() can be called even after a has been released?

To make sure a has been released when the child thread call func(), I add weak pointer check, see code v2.

This time, the child thread returns from lambda directly and does not call func(). It means object a indeed has been released when the child thread initiates to run.

Could anyone help give some instructions?

Comment: It can be easy explained, provided you know how member function is generated in assembler code. Member function is just normal procedure which takes `this` as first parameter. Now your code works because in `func` you don't access any data member on `this` pointer so there is no place where segmentation fault may happen. Add some variables member to `A` class and access them inside `func`.

Comment: Thanks, @rafix07. If I wrote this->func(), it also works. But after a has been released, the "this" pointer should be invalid, so call "->" on "this" should have problems, why it also works?

Comment: In assembler `this->func(),` is translated to : [1] push `this` onto stack, [2] call `func`, and `this` is seen in `func` procedure as its first parameter. So here you don't trigger segmentation fault. But in short, it is just Undefined Behaviour and you should not rely on this code.